# Flash Builder 4.5 Mobile App ... Scroller and Preloaded Images

Tags: apache-flex, image, mobile, air, preload

I got some Images in my scroller component... while scrolling the scroller sometimes hang for a second... i think the image is loading... is it possible to load the image before the scroller is on the position?!....

Comment: When you say "Scroller" do you mean a List component? Or something else?

Comment: I imagine his code looks like `<s:Scroller><s:Image source="someImage"/></s:Scroller>`. Is your image embedded or are you linking to a path?

Comment: some code: `<s:Scroller id="snapper" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
  <s:HGroup gap="0" width="100%" height="100%">
   <s:Image width="{snapper.width}" height="100%"
      source="1314004166_768x1024_elegant-scenery-iphone-5-wallpaper.jpg"/>
   .... // more Images
  </s:HGroup> 
  
 </s:Scroller>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to load each image and then add them to the scroller. You can use Multiloader library (http://code.google.com/p/multiloader/) to know when all images has been loaded.

for example:

```
var multiloader:MultiLoader();

function loadImages():void
{
   multiLoader = new MultiLoader();
   multiLoader.addTask("image1.jpg", "img1", MultiLoader.MOVIE);
   multiLoader.addTask("image2.jpg", "img2", MultiLoader.MOVIE);
   multiLoader.addTask("image3.jpg", "img3", MultiLoader.MOVIE);
   multiLoader.addTask("image4.jpg", "img4", MultiLoader.MOVIE);
   multiLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
   multiLoader.start();
}

function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
    var image:Image;

    for (var i:uint=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        image = new Image();
        image.percentHeight = 100;
        image.width = snapper.width;
        image.source = multiloader.getItemLoader(i);
        snapper.addElement(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok... but what if the phone is out of memory... is there a function to remove that image from memory?